# radio button return through inner html in c# file for answer selection

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Here is the c# file code in which i want to get radio button to every out put so that i can chosen option as we do in "mcqs".

```
public HtmlString questions_sec1()
{
    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["USERID"]);
    List<DAO_getQuestiones> get_question_sec1 = new List<DAO_getQuestiones>(DAO_getQuestiones.get_question_sec1(userid)); // data to      fech first section
    string content = "";
    HtmlString theEnvelopePlease = null;
    try
    {
        foreach (var obj in get_question_sec1)
        {
            content = content + "<tr><td> " + obj.get_question_id + "</td> <td>" + obj.get_answer_question + "</td><td>"+  <input type="radio" name="d" value="data"> DATA +"</td></tr>";
        }

        theEnvelopePlease = new HtmlString(content);
        return theEnvelopePlease;    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        content = content + ex;
        theEnvelopePlease = new HtmlString(content);
        return theEnvelopePlease;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of html call which is returning the function of cs file for rendering:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.</th>
      <th>Questions</th>
      <th>Answers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    < %:questions_sec1() % >
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Question: I want the radio button to every out put of answer so that i can chose one option and one more thing.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [RadioButtonList Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295394.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to add form element with HTML string into ASP.NET form.

Instead, I suggest you to use a 'Repeater':

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
     <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sr.</th>
          <th>Questions</th>
          <th>Answers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
        <td> <%#Eval("get_question_id ") %> </td>
        <td> <%#Eval("get_answer_question  ") %> </td>
        <td> <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton" runat="Server" Text="DATA" /> </td>
     </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
     </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

And in your .cs file, bind the data to the Repeater like this:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = get_question_sec1;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Here is the MSDN link of Repeater: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response but i don't want to use biukt in controls of tool box from asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responce but i dn't want to you built in control from the tool box of asp.net.